# Vue - how to override a prop of a wrapper component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, quasar-framework

I have created a wrapper component, which wraps a Quasar [q-select](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select) like this:

```html
<template lang="pug">
  q-select(
    :options="organisations"
    option-value="id"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
    :option-label="item => item.details.name"
    :label="$t('organisations.label')")
</template>
```

And named it `OrganisationSelect`. I want the label to have a default value, taken from `i18n`. Now I want to be able to override this `:label` prop when I use this component like this:

```
div.col-4
 OrganiastionSelect(
  :rules="[val => !!val || 'Please select an Organisation']"
  v-model='organisation'
  :label="$t('organisation.someOtherLabel')"
  dense
).col-6
```

It does not take this label *someOtherLabel*. It takes always the *internal* label.

## Question:

Is such prop overriding possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you have each of this `q-select` props on your wrapper component, or are you simply `extend`ing it?

Comment: By using `v-bind="$attrs"` all props are propagated like like `:rules` and `dense`

Comment: Sometimes relying on `$attrs` may not be ideal as it would also bind any native DOM attributes, unless disabled by `inheritAttrs`.

Comment: uses `render` function instead of template.

Answer (score 1):

`OrganisationSelect` could provide a `label` [prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#props) that defaults to `$t('organisations.label')`, and bind that prop to `<q-select>.label`:

```html
<template lang="pug">
  q-select(
    ...
    :label="label"
  )
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    label: {
      type: String,
      default() {
        return this.$t('organisations.label')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/default-label-for-qselect-wrapper-t52o1?file=/src/components/OrganisationSelect.vue:300-444)